# Installing Simple Arms

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!  I was trying to follow the turtlebot arm setup tutorial and I got the following error when trying to install simple arms:

```
$ rosmake --rosdep-install simple_arms
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['simple_arms']                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/marc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111013-160200
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['simple_arms'] to:
[]                                
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['simple_arms']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Does anyone have an idea of why I am getting this error, and how I should go about fixing it?

In addition to this, I am getting the following error upon trying to run the next step, to install the turtlebot_arm software.

```
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ hg clone hg https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm
abort: repository hg not found!
```

I don't know if this is because of the previous problem or if that is it's own problem.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you very much!

Thank you very much!  I have attached my command history for getting it set up below so that everything can be seen:

```
marc@marc-howard:~$ cd ~/ros
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ svn co http://vanadium-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simple_arms/
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping/include
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping/include/simple_grasping
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping/manifest.xml
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping/src
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping/CMakeLists.txt
A    simple_arms/simple_grasping/Makefile
A    simple_arms/stack.xml
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/manifest.xml
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/bin
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/bin/relax_arm_server.py
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/bin/reset_arm_server.py
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/CMakeLists.txt
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/action
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/action/RelaxArm.action
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/action/ResetArm.action
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/Makefile
A    simple_arms/CMakeLists.txt
A    simple_arms/Makefile
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/manifest.xml
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/msg
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/msg/ArmAction.msg
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_arm_navigation_server.cpp
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/nodes
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/nodes/simple_arm_server_test.py
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/nodes/simple_arm_server.py
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/nodes/constraint_aware_simple_arm_server.py
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/srv
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/srv/GetTrajectoryValidity.srv
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/mainpage.dox
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/launch
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/launch/arm_server.launch
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/CMakeLists.txt
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/action
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/action/MoveArm.action
A    simple_arms/simple_arm_server/Makefile
Checked out revision 587.
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ rosmake --rosdep-install simple_arms
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['simple_arms']                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/marc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111013-160043
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['simple_arms'] to:
[]                                
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['simple_arms']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ ls
simple_arms
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ cd simple_arms/
marc@marc-howard:~/ros/simple_arms$ rosmake --rosdep-install simple_arms
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['simple_arms']                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/marc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111013-160108
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['simple_arms'] to:
[]                                
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['simple_arms']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
marc@marc-howard:~/ros/simple_arms$ cd ~/ros
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ ls
simple_arms
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ ls simple_arms/
CMakeLists.txt  simple_arm_actions  simple_grasping
Makefile        simple_arm_server   stack.xml
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ rosmake --rosdep-install simple_arms
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['simple_arms']                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/marc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111013-160200
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['simple_arms'] to:
[]                                
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['simple_arms']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ 
marc@marc-howard:~/ros$ hg clone hg https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm
abort: repository hg not found!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11542/installing-simple-arms/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-10-13**:
Thank you, the new one worked!  I just want to let you know that I just copied and pasted from the tutorial, however, so I went and updated that!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-10-13**:
it looks like your hg clone command is wrong.. hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is simple_arms actually on your ROS path (is ~/ros on your path? can you "roscd simple_arm_server"?). You might also try a "rospack profile" to update things.

Also, I just updated the ROS tutorial, you can actually install simple arms from debs now:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-simple-arms
```

turtlebot_arm will be in debs shortly.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-10-14**:
Great, if you select the checkmark next to my answer it will mark this question as answered.

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-10-14**:
~/ros is on my path.  I was not able to resolve this issue, but the deb install worked fine.  Thank you very much!